# How to get an app off the recent list when sharing files?

Tags: 8.1, apps, sharing

When sharing files, recently used apps are supposed to be listed at the top, under the "recent" heading, with the rest below, under "more".

My problem is that the "recent" list includes an app (Instagram BETA) that I haven't used for at least a month (since switching to 6tag). How long do I need to wait before it's removed from the list? Or can I remove it manually somehow? Long-pressing on the apps in the list does nothing.

Update: I found that the maximum number of apps in the "recent" list is six. So after sharing to six different apps I finally managed to push Instagram off the list. However, today I found it had crept back there, even though I haven't actually used it since (and it isn't allowed to run in the background either). Does anyone have any idea as to why that's happening?

Comment: Is uninstalling the app an option? Otherwise you might need to share to a few other apps to get it flushed out.

Comment: @Thomas I tried sharing to other apps; it seems the Recent list just grows longer and longer.

Comment: @Thomas I'd prefer not to uninstall, if possible. Also, I've been using other apps like 6tag, yet Instagram persists in that list. What's more, 6tag is *removed* from the "recent" list after a while, usually when I don't use it for a couple of days.

Comment: What happens if you select Instagram?

Comment: @Shawn Instagram opens, as expected. And stays in the "recent" list, if that's what you were asking.

Comment: @Indrek Oops sorry! Should have read the question again. I thought you had said you *uninstalled* Instagram.

Comment: A few days ago I tried sharing to 6 different apps (the maximum for the "recent" list, it seems), which finally pushed Instagram off the list. Today I discovered that it's back, apparently having replaced 6tag. At this point I think I'll just uninstall it, but it'd still be nice to know what's going on.

Comment: @Indrek For me only the last six apps are stored in the list. Nothing happened like Instagram came back for you. You said it replaced 6tag. Does this happened after an update to 6tag? May be after update WP could have recognized it as a new app (sometimes happens with my data sense).